# Given $\frac1{x+y+z}=\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z$ what can be said about $(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, symmetric-polynomials

> If $\frac1{x+y+z}=\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z$ where $xyz(x+y+z)\ne0$, then the value of $(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)$ is
>
> (A) zero
> (B) positive
> (C) negative
> (D) non-negative

I substituted $x=-y$ and the equality was established. In the given expression the factor $(x+y)$ would be 0 and the result would be 0. But how should I proceed to show that 0 is the only possible result? I did some algebraic manipulations which do not seem to be of any use. I also believe that we can assume the variables can only be real – this might somehow play a role. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)$ is symmetric in $x,y,z$, so it can be expressed as
$$
a(x+y+z)^3+b(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)+cxyz
$$
for some $a,b,c$: this follows from the theory of symmetric polynomials.

With $x=1$, $y=0$, $z=0$ we obtain
$$
a=0
$$
With $x=1$, $y=1$, $z=0$ we obtain
$$
8a+2b=2
$$
With $x=1$, $y=1$, $z=1$ we obtain
$$
27a+9b+c=8
$$
Thus $a=0$, $b=1$ and $c=-1$. So
$$
(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)=(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)-xyz
$$
which you can also verify by expanding the products.

The initial condition tells you that
$$
xyz=(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)
$$

Comment: nice solution. +1 and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac1{x+y+z}=\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z$$

$$\to \frac1{x+y+z}=\frac{yz+xz+xy}{xyz}$$

$$\to xyz=(yz+xz+xy)(x+y+z)$$

$$\to xyz=(yz+xz+xy)(x+y+z)$$

$$\to xyz=(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)-xyz$$

$$\to 0=(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)$$